# Could not connect the action btnPressed to target of class NSViewController

Tags: objective-c, macos, xcode5

I did search and could not find a similar problem as mine.

I have a parent view (AppDelegate) and a child view (NSViewController) with a NSButton on it.

In my parent view (AppDelegate), I use IB to add a CustomView and NSViewController in the MainMenu.xib and use the following code to change the view to Child

```
AppDelegate.h -

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

@end


AppDelegate.m -

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "Child.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSView *myCustomView;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSViewController *myViewController;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

    Child *childView = [[Child alloc] init];
    [[self.myViewController view] removeFromSuperview];
    self.myViewController = [childView initWithNibName:@"Child" bundle:nil];
    [self.myCustomView addSubview:[self.myViewController view]];
    [[self.myViewController view]setFrame:[self.myCustomView bounds]];

}
```

Here is the Child (NSViewController) , I use IB to add a button and link it with my Child.

```
Child.h -

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface Child : NSViewController

@end


Child.m -

#import "Child.h"

@interface Child ()

@end

@implementation Child

- (IBAction)btnPressed:(id)sender {
}

@end
```

Problem is there is no compile error but when I run it. It shows

```
2014-10-09 22:51:43.952 Test[1439:303] Could not connect the action btnPressed: to target of class NSViewController
```

Child can catch the button press event. It seems to me Xcode complain about the button action is not linked with the parent view (AppDelegate).

How can I get rid of the warning?
Does Apple allow a OSX app with such warning?

Comment: did u connect the button to your action method?

Comment: Yes, I did. That why the btnPressed got called when I hit the button. The application itself is running fine. I just don't know how to get rid of the message. I want to upload the project here but I don't know how.

Comment: It is very simple to reproduce it.

Comment: I've tried to upload the project but I don't know how. It is very simple to reproduce it in Xcode5. Step 1. Create a new Cocoa Project. Step 2. Add a custom view and view controller in the MainMenu.xib. Step 3. Create a new Cocoa Class ("Child") with base class "NSViewController". Don't forget to check the xib support. Step 4. Create a NSButton in the Child.xib and link the action with Child.m. Step5. Copy my applicationDidFinishLaunching() into yours and run.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the below line :-

```
Child *childView = [[Child alloc] init];
self.myViewController = [childView initWithNibName:@"Child" bundle:nil];
```

With modified line:-

```
self.myViewController = [[childView alloc]initWithNibName:@"Child" bundle:nil];
```

**Note:**- Please make sure that your mentioned xib name should be correct.